# With styled components how to bring in an external CSS file for createGlobalStyle?

Tags: css, styled-components

I have a css file and I'm trying to figure out how to bring in and per memory I thought I read this in the docs but I'm getting an error. Given the scrollbar file of:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Scrollbar = styled.css`
  html {
    --scrollbarBG: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color01};
    --thumbBG: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color04};
  }
  body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
  }
  body {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: var(--thumbBG) var(--scrollbarBG);
  }
  body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: var(--scrollbarBG);
  }
  body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: var(--thumbBG);
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 4px solid var(--scrollbarBG);
  }
`
```

My error is:

> WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'withConfig' of
> undefined

In my theme directory is my GlobalStyles.js:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'

// CSS
import Scrollbar from './Scrollbar'

const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  ${Scrollbar}
`

export default GlobalStyles
```

When I search the docs I'm not seeing it in advanced. Searching the site I've read:

- [Import CSS File to Styled Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49337702/import-css-file-to-styled-component)
- [How to move css-in-js (Styled Components) to an external css files during build using webpack - ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63394456/how-to-move-css-in-js-styled-components-to-an-external-css-files-during-build)
- [loading external css file just for one react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829706/loading-external-css-file-just-for-one-react-component)
- [React + Styled Components: Am I supposed to avoid CSS files altogether?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162369/react-styled-components-am-i-supposed-to-avoid-css-files-altogether)

In styled components what is the correct way to bring in the css file to createGlobalStyle?

Comment: Still wonder for the same thing +1